# I have a linq List Select issue

Tags: linq, select

If you have a collection/List<> of objects how do you select distinct records out of that collection/List<> ?

for example, I'm doing the following but getting the same count for both:

```
 var list = List<Order>;
 list.add( new Order { Status = "Completed" });
 list.add( new Order { Status = "Completed" });
 list.add( new Order { Status = "Completed" });
 list.add( new Order { Status = "Processing" });

 var = completed = list.Select(x => x.Status == "Completed").Count();
 var = Processing = list.Select(x => x.Status == "Processing").Count();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two problems and one simplification:

- Your variable declaration shouldn't have an `=` between `var` and the variable name
- For filtering, you should use `Where` instead of `Count`
- It would be simpler to use the overload of `Count` which takes a predicate in the first place...

So:

```
var completed = list.Count(x => x.Status == "Completed");
var processing = list.Count(x => x.Status == "Processing");
```

Alternatively, you could go create a dictionary of "count by status":

```
var counts = list.GroupBy(x => x.Status)
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
var completed = counts["Completed"];
var processing = counts["Processing"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the same count because you are creating result that consist of `true` and `false` values, but when you count them they are still as many as there are items in the collection.

You should use `Where` instead of `Select`, or simply put the condition in the `Count` instead:

```
int completed = list.Count(x => x.Status == "Completed");
int processing = list.Count(x => x.Status == "Processing");
```